# Unwrap Typescript fields in Knockout

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, type-conversion, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a domain class, with all the fields being primitives, string, number or boolean. For simplicity, let's work with a bike:

```
interface Bike {
  wheels: number;
  isMTB: boolean;
  brand: string;
}
```

In my application, I'm using `knockout-mapping` so I can easily make all the fields editable, e.g. `wheels` becomes `ko.Observable<number>`. I have created therefore a type to help me type it, e.g.

```
export type MappedObject<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: ko.Observable<T[key]>;
};
```

I'm usually maintaining a collection of editable bikes, e.g. `bikes = ko.observableArray<MappedObject<Bike>>();`

And pushing one editable bike like this:

```
const bike = { wheels: 2, isMTB: true, brand: "Cross" }; // Bike
const editBike = ko.mapping.fromJS(bike); // MappedObject<Bike>
bikes.push(editBike);
```

When I'm saving my changes, I'm converting the collection of editable bikes into an array of plain bike objects using either `ko.toJS` or `ko.mapping.toJS`. Both unwraps any `observable` fields into their primitive value, so for `bikes` defined above, `ko.toJS` returns, at runtime, a `Bike[]`. However, in Typescript, it doesn't return that, it returns `MappedObject<Bike>[]`.

For `ko.toJS` there is a definition:

```
type Unwrapped<T> = T extends ko.Subscribable<infer R> ? R :
    T extends Record<any, any> ? { [P in keyof T]: Unwrapped<T[P]> } : T;

export function toJS<T>(rootObject: T): Unwrapped<T>;
```

For `knockout-mapping`, there isn't any typing so I tried to define it myself:

```
export type UnmappedObject<T> = T extends ko.ObservableArray<MappedObject<infer U>>
  ? U[]
  : T extends ko.Observable<MappedObject<infer R>>
  ? R
  : T;

// Note: this is not containing ALL the properties exposed
export interface KnockoutMapping {
  fromJS: <T>(object: T) => MappedObject<T>;
  toJS: <T>(object: T) => UnmappedObject<T>;
}
```

Note that `UnmappedObject<T>` is inspired by `Unwrapped<T>` shipped with `knockout`, but it doesn't work as I expect because `ko.mapping.toJS` will return `Unmapped<ObservableArray<MappedObject<Bike>>>`. `toJS` should convert both editable object to plain object and array of editable objects to array of plain objects, hence my attempt to guess if `T` extends `ko.ObservableArray` or `ko.Observable`.

What can I change to have properly unwrapping for the fields of each editable object in the array? For clarity, here is what I expect:

```
const bike = { wheels: 2, isMTB: true, brand: "Cross" }; // Bike
const editBike = ko.mapping.fromJS(bike); // MappedObject<Bike>
const customizedBike = ko.mapping.toJS(editBike); // Bike

const bikes = ko.observableArray<MappedObject<Bike>>();
bikes.push(editBike);
const customizedBikes = ko.mapping.toJS(bikes); // Bike[]
```

Comment: Could it be that you need one more check in the `UnmappedObject` typing? Where it says `: T;`, I would expect `T extends MappedObject<infer S> ? S : T;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was close to the final solution, I was missing a few cases here and there:

```
export type MappedObject<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: ko.Observable<T[key]>;
};

export type UnmappedObject<T> = T extends ko.ObservableArray<MappedObject<infer U>>
  ? U[]
  : T extends ko.Observable<MappedObject<infer V>>
  ? V
  : T extends ko.Computed<MappedObject<infer S>>
  ? S
  : T extends ko.Computed<MappedObject<infer X>[]>
  ? X[]
  : T extends MappedObject<infer W>
  ? W
  : T;

// Note: this is not containing ALL the properties exposed
export interface KnockoutMapping {
  fromJS: <T>(object: T) => MappedObject<T>;
  toJS: <T>(object: T) => UnmappedObject<T>;
}
```